# Vim errorformat: how to ignore a line but leave it visible?

Tags: vim

I know how to get Vim to show only the error messages in the quick fix window, and hide everything else, but that's not quite what I want.

I would like the quick fix window to have my complete build log, for context, but with only the actual error messages highlighted and enabled for `:cnext`.

I can almost get this: the default behaviour when no pattern matches is to do the right thing; vim preceeds these lines with double bar, and that's fine:

```
|| cc -c myfile.c -o myfile.o
myfile.c|123| error: ......
```

The problem is when I have a line that matches an error pattern, but shouldn't (basically anything that has a random colon). I can add a `%-G` pattern to ignore it, but this also hides it from view, which isn't helpful.

E.g. `-DVAR="1:2"` might get tagged as an error like this:

```
cc -DVAR="1 |2| " -c myfile.c -o myfile.o
myfile.c|123| error: ......
```

... in which case I *don't* want it to hide the `cc` line, but I do want to ignore it for error processing.

How can I write an exception pattern that just says "pretend nothing matched and do the default double-bar thing"?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to put an format string at the beginning of `errorformat` which matches `cc` (and excludes all other errors) but also lets the entire string (including `cc`) be considered as the message `%m`.

If you say `cc%m` then the `cc` will not be part of `%m`.  Only the characters after `cc` will be part of `%m`.

A solution is to use a zero-width look-ahead regex, like explained here: [Vim errorformat: include part of expression in message string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375881/vim-errorformat-include-part-of-expression-in-message-string)

The order of the error strings in `'errorformat'` is very important.  You'll want your new error string to earlier than any other error strings that may match this string the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks, but this flags the line as an error (i.e. :cc and :cn stop there), which is not what I want. It should be just inactive context, like every other line that matches nothing.